# How to read input after calling program, gives: "read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: bash, unix

I'm calling a program called arecord (see the code below). It takes in microphone input, and I stop it by pressing Ctrl+C to continue with the rest of the script.

I next want it to do is read my input (c or r) to see whether it should break out of the loop

However, the input isn't read, and the error "read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable".

I guess it has something to do with the exit code or input stream, but I can't go further with it.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    # Record the audio
    arecord -f cd -c 1 -t wav sound.wav

    # Recording now finished, get user input
    read -p "Continue or repeat recording? [c, r]: " input
    if [ "${input}" == "c" ]
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution to this. Trying to do it in Python now!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not simple, it depends how `arecord` handles `SIGINT` (ctrl+c), read [this](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) if you want to understand what exactly is happening. Anyway, i would recommend not to use SIGINT in that way, but:

run `arecord` in background (with `&` at the end), get the pid (`arecodr_pid=$!`), then `read` something like *`enough`*, `kill -2 $arecodr_pid`
and after that you can do `# Recording now finished, get user input`

If `arecord` knows to handle other signals, you can use `kill -<signal num> $arecord_pid` Do not use -9, processes can not handle it and in most cases your out file will be corrupted.

Comment: So with "read something like `enough`, `kill -2 $arecodr_pid`" would that allow me to quickly stop arecord recording? I'm puzzled how I would tell it to stop once I'm finished the sound (which is of adjustable length).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read directly from tty:

```
read -p "Your prompt " -r </dev/tty
```

instead of simply:

```
read -p "Your prompt " -n 1 -r
```

In a script having a similar issue, it worked.